# Best way to cache huge mysql queries?

Tags: php, mysql, caching, memcached

At the moment I'm using Memcache to store my php pdo mysql queries and it's working just as intended.

However I would like to create a single page sitemap with ~50,000 urls and think I may need a different way to cache this query. Ideally I'd only want to perform the query once per day and  think that keeping 50,000 ids and titles in memcache for that amount of time would be a complete waste of space?

Would it be better to gzip the files into some sort of temporary .txt file? or a different method completely?

Comment: Why not just 'cache' those links in the actual sitemap file? If it's only built once a day, then there's no point in spending the cache overhead. Cache is for frequently accessed/expensive to build data.

Comment: Depends, you could also consider a secondary DB like Mongo, or a search DB like Solr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Marc's comments. Generate the file once per day, perhaps with a cron job.

I refer you to this statement about [sitemaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps), which you should consider:

> Sitemap files have a limit of 50,000 URLs and 10 megabytes per
>   sitemap. Sitemaps can be compressed using gzip, reducing bandwidth
>   consumption.

Currently, I'm generating my sitemap dynamically, but switching it over to a cron job is on my to do list.

Comment: How about a php function to create a timestamped sitemap file that contains the result, then use a query to check the timestamp of the file, if it's older than 1 day then rebuild the file with a a new query if younger then just load the result, would also be simple to compress that file. Could also md5 the cache filename so it's not easily publicly viewable.

Answer (score 0):

Config "MySQL Query Cache" and "Apache Cache" correctly and forget about doing all this stuff in your code.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache.html